# Load strings.xml from sd card to application android

Tags: android

Is it possible to load strings.xml from sd card instead of application res/values/... Search on the web but didn't find any tutorials.  My thought is download the xml to sd card then save the strings element to an array.

```
public void stringsxml(){
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + ".strings.xml");

        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        try {
              //use buffering, reading one line at a time
              //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
              BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
              try {
                String line = null; //not declared within while loop
                /*
                * readLine is a bit quirky :
                * it returns the content of a line MINUS the newline.
                * it returns null only for the END of the stream.
                * it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in a row.
                */
                while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
                  contents.append(line);
                  contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                }
              }
              finally {
                input.close();
              }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            String data= contents.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually it is semi-possible, but you have to create a derivate LayoutInflater which will replace string codes with thus read strings.

I have documented my attempts and failings together with initial implementation [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2223839).

Summary: simple strings work, string arrays do not

Comment: according to you download strings.xml is better than .sqllite or vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Check [Android decoumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) about resources:

> The Android SDK tools compile your application's resources into the application binary at build time. To use a resource, you must install it correctly in the source tree (inside your project's res/ directory) and build your application.

Resources are built-in into the application binary and you can't read them from a file.

Comment: So instead of using strings.xml we can stored language into .sqllite database and update the database from server

Comment: Yes, but then you cannot call it resources.